# react-hook-form V7 passing register props to custom field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, yup, react-hook-form

I want to create a custom input with new register method by passing into props of `react-hook-form`, I have the same message everytime:

> TypeError: path.split is not a function

https://gyazo.com/414ea28dbe2b016e5b0739660efdc84b

My custom input

```
function Field({
    name,
    register,
    placeholder,
    type,
    value,
    onChange,
    defaultValue,
    errors,
    children
}){
    return(
        <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label htmlFor={name}>{children}</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
                size="lg"
                placeholder={placeholder}
                type={type ? type : "text"}
                id={name}
                // name={name}
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
                {...register({name})}
                defaultValue={defaultValue}
            />
            {errors && <span className="text-danger">{errors.message}</span>}
        </Form.Group>
    );
}
```

And my form part where I call my custom input:

```
const {register, formState : { errors }, handleSubmit} = useForm({
        mode: "onTouched",
        resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    });
...
<Field
  name="login"
  register={register}
  errors={errors.login}
>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [migration guide](https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/) to v7:

> ### Custom register
>
> You will no longer need the name attribute for custom
> register, you can supply the name of the input straight way.
>
> ```
> - register({ name: 'test' })
> + register('test')
> ```

It looks like `react-hook-form` is trying to split the name string in case you have a nested field:

```
'test.0.nested'.split('.')
```

But with the new version you should be supply a string instead of an object with a `name` property so:

```
{ name: 'test.0.nested' }.split('.')
```

Throws the error.